# logging method calls without an external tool or external library in java

Tags: java, multithreading, debugging, logging

I am trying to make a java class that will log the method calls of a multithreading java program I already have the part where it can save the information into a file to the desktop but I have not managed to find a way to get the method calls. I have tried using Runtime.getRuntime().traceMethodCalls(true) and using the Thread.getAllStackTraces().values() and looping through the StackTraceElement's. 
Visit https://github.com/NamelessSuperCoder/Class-Debugging.git to see my current code. Please tell what I should do to improve and how to make my classes work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be possible to log all method calls, without literally writing a log statement, per each method or without an external tool. Probably the easiest way to accomplish that task would involve aspect oriented programming with a tool like AspectJ. In fact, I even found an article on how to do this, http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/01/aop-aspectj-java-method-logging.html. You might be able to build your own tools using a proxy to all of your classes.

Comment: is there some other way? because I can not seem to make AspectJ work on my current wpilib java project

Answer (score 0):

Have a reference to your logging class in your other class. Set th logging class up as a singleton so there is only ever one instance of it. Give it some method that accepts string to be put into the log, and then call the method in the logging class form your other class' methods...

```
class Logger {

    static addLogEntry(String logEntry) {
        // some method to add log entry to your log
    }
}


class Foo {

    Logger aLogger;

    public Foo() {
        // get your singleton Logger instance
        aLogger = getLogger();
    }

    public void someMethodInThisClass() {
        aLogger.addLogEntry("in someMethodInSomeClass");
    }


}
```

probably a more elegant way to do it, but that should work.

Comment: this is not exactly what I wanted I want to have a class that in runtime can get all the method call and save them in a file.